# phoenix websocket behind nginx connection refused

Tags: apache, nginx, channel, apache-phoenix

Cannot make phoenix channel work behind nginx with also apache reverse proxy before nginx.

the website is ok but the socket connection cannot be established. socket is ok in dev mode where everything is ok. there is no authorization setup in phoenix

```
defp authorized?(_payload) do
    true
 end
```

**the error message is**

```
2017/04/29 09:40:50 [error] 10451#10451: failed (111: Connection refused) 
while connecting to upsteam, client: 192.168.0.10, 
server: somehost.com, 
request: "GET /socket/websocket?token=undefined&vsn=1.0.0 HTTP/1.1",
upstream:"http://phoenix3/socket/websocket?token=undefined&vsn=1.0.0", 
host: "somehost.com"
```

**following the guides on this topic here is the setup I came up with**

in user_socket.ex

```
transport :websocket, Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket, check_origin: ["//somehost.com"]
```

in endpoint

```
config :myapp, MyApp.Endpoint,                                               
  http: [port: {:system, "PORT"}],                                                   
  url: [host: "somehost.com", port: 80],                               
  cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/manifest.json"
```

in nginx

**nb** X-Real-IP or X-Cluster-Client-IP both fail

```
upstream phoenix3 {                                                                  
   server localhost:4020 max_fails=5 fail_timeout=60s;                           
}                                                                                    
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {                                             
 default upgrade;                                                            
 '' close;                                                                   
}                                                                                    
server {                                                                             
  listen 80;                                                                   
  listen [::]:80;                                                              
  server_name somehost.com;                                      

   access_log /home/user1/appdir/log/access.log;                             
   error_log  /home/user1/appdir/log/error.log;                              
   location / {                                                                 

   # Proxy Headers                                                              
   proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;                                    
   # proxy_set_header X-Cluster-Client-Ip $remote_addr;                         
   proxy_http_version 1.1;                                                     
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;                
   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;                                           


 # The Important Websocket Bits!                                             
 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;                                     
 proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;                            

 proxy_pass http://phoenix3;                                                 
 proxy_redirect off;                                                         

 }
```

in apache (gets the real world connection)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>      
  ServerName somehost.com
   ProxyPreserveHost On                                                             
   ProxyRequests off                                                                
   ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.26/                                                 
   ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.26/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: what is your Phoenix port? 8765 is the standard unless you change it.

Comment: it is changed to 4020 as mentioned in the nginx config at the top

Comment: I was thinking maybe apache is preventing the websocket connection. I tried to plug directly from apache to phoenix without nginx and the websocket still does not work. so maybe an apache config ?

Answer (score 1):

**the problem was the apache configuration.**
the nginx configuration is ok and the phoenix configuration is also ok

in apache virtual host, needed to add

```
ProxyPass /socket/ ws://192.168.0.26/socket/                                     
ProxyPassReverse /socket/ ws://192.168.0.26/socket/
```

before the first block, and then add an additionnal apache module

```
a2enmod proxy_wstunnel
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: so the problem was that the incoming ws://somehost.com call was translated to http:/somehost.com  by the original proxy directive and it is also required to upgrade the connection with proxy_wstunnel